# How to groupby consecutive values in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, cumsum

I have a column in a DataFrame with values:

```
[1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1]
```

How can I group them like this?

```
[1,1] [-1] [1] [-1, -1]
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1]})` is a better testcase, to make sure we catch all groups, not just length-two

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by custom `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1]})
print(df)
   a
0  1
1  1
2 -1
3  1
4 -1
5 -1

print(df['a'].ne(df['a'].shift()).cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    4
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

```
for i, g in df.groupby(df['a'].ne(df['a'].shift()).cumsum()):
    print(i)
    print(g)
    print(g.a.tolist())

1
   a
0  1
1  1
[1, 1]
2
   a
2 -1
[-1]
3
   a
3  1
[1]
4
   a
4 -1
5 -1
[-1, -1]
```

Comment: In case you want to use this solution to `.groupby()` consecutive dates with 1 hour difference, change the condition to `df['date'].diff() != pd.Timedelta('1 hour')`

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5494 asks for the same behaviour with the `itertools.groupby()`, but it's `Contributions Welcome, No action on 6 Jul 2018`

Comment: Instead of `==`, there's actually a vectorized `.ne()` function: `df.a.ne(df.a.shift())`

Answer (score 21):

Using `groupby` from `itertools` data from Jez

```
from itertools import groupby
[ list(group) for key, group in groupby(df.a.values.tolist())]
Out[361]: [[1, 1], [-1], [1], [-1, -1]]
```

Comment: this answer is more explicit than the accepted `cumsum()` solution

Comment: from the document: `The operation of groupby() is similar to the uniq filter in Unix. It generates a break or new group every time the value of the key function changes`

Comment: While this is a literal answer to the question, it loses the oft-needed labeling of the group of consecutive values.

Answer (score 9):

[**`Series.diff`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) is another way to mark the group boundaries (`a!=a.shift` means `a.diff!=0`):

```py
consecutives = df['a'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()

# 0    1
# 1    1
# 2    2
# 3    3
# 4    4
# 5    4
# Name: a, dtype: int64
```

And to turn these groups into a Series of lists (see the other answers for a list of lists), aggregate with [**`groupby.agg`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) or [**`groupby.apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```py
df['a'].groupby(consecutives).agg(list)

# a
# 1      [1, 1]
# 2        [-1]
# 3         [1]
# 4    [-1, -1]
# Name: a, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with string values:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(['A','A','A','BB','BB','CC','A','A','BB'], columns=['a'])
string_groups = sum([['%s_%s' % (i,n) for i in g] for n,(k,g) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(s.a))],[])

>>> string_groups 
['A_0', 'A_0', 'A_0', 'BB_1', 'BB_1', 'CC_2', 'A_3', 'A_3', 'BB_4']

grouped = s.groupby(string_groups, sort=False).agg(list)
grouped.index = grouped.index.str.split('_').str[0]

>>> grouped
            a
A   [A, A, A]
BB   [BB, BB]
CC       [CC]
A      [A, A]
BB       [BB]
```

As a separate function:

```
def groupby_consec(df, col):
    string_groups = sum([['%s_%s' % (i, n) for i in g]
                         for n, (k, g) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(df[col]))], [])
    return df.groupby(string_groups, sort=False)
```