# group the same consecutive values in pandas and store: values, indices, and column slices

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
v1=list(np.random.rand(30))
v2=list(np.random.rand(30))
mydf=pd.DataFrame(data=zip(v1,v2),columns=['var1','var2'])
```

then I apply some boolean conditions on some variables

```
mydf['cond1']=mydf['var1']>0.2
mydf['cond2']=mydf['var1']>0.8


mydf['cond1']=
0 False
1 True
2 True
3 False
4 False
5 True
6 False
....
```

I would like to group in blocks where 'cond1' (or 'cond2') is True, and for each group store:

- the value of the group: True/False
- the index of the start, and of the end, of the block: e.g.
  1,2
  5,5
- the 2 values of `var2` at index of the start, and of the end,
- all the values of `var1` between the index of the start, and of the end, as an iterable (list of np.array)

this is one example of returned values:

```
summary=
'Start' 'End' 'Start_var2' 'End_var2' 'Value' 'var1'
 1        2    0.3217381    0.454543   True    [0.25,0.26]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, Let's try something like this:

```
mydf.groupby(mydf.cond1.diff().cumsum(), as_index=False)\
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.iloc[0].name,
                                x.iloc[-1].name, 
                                x.iloc[0]['var2'], 
                                x.iloc[-1]['var2'], 
                                x.iloc[0]['cond1'], 
                                x.var1.tolist()],
                                index=['Start','End','Start_var2',
                                       'End_var2','Value','var1']))
```

Output:

```
   Start  End  Start_var2  End_var2  Value                                               var1
0      1   13    0.580713  0.772878   True  [0.9080110836630401, 0.34879731608699105, 0.63...
1     14   14    0.688374  0.688374  False                              [0.11739843719148924]
2     15   15    0.204304  0.204304   True                               [0.3010533582011998]
3     16   17    0.470689  0.808964  False         [0.14526373397045378, 0.09218609736837002]
4     18   20    0.675035  0.087408   True  [0.6029321967069232, 0.3641874497564469, 0.564...
5     21   21    0.346795  0.346795  False                               [0.1913357207205566]
6     22   29    0.944366  0.845753   True  [0.6769058596527606, 0.2155054472756598, 0.278...
```

Comment: perfect.nice, compact and without explict loops

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802800/pandas-dataframe-how-to-groupby-consecutive-values). `i` gives you the group number, and the `index` of `g` can be used to get the `var` values.

```
v1=list(np.random.rand(30))
v2=list(np.random.rand(30))
df=pd.DataFrame(data=zip(v1,v2),columns=['var1','var2'])

df['cond1']=df['var1']>0.2
df['cond2']=df['var1']>0.8

for i, g in df.groupby([(df['cond1'] != df['cond1'].shift()).cumsum()]):
    print (i)
    print (g)
    print (g['cond1'].tolist())
    print(g['cond1'].index[0])#can get var values from this
```

Comment: that's very close. any chance of avoiding the for loop?it is a long df

Comment: I doubt it, `groupby` returns an object that you're gonna have to unpack somehow. I don't consider myself an expert though. The person who answered the linked question might be able to help though.