# Using Pandas, how can we copy the initial value of a state to each row as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

The question that this was marked as a duplicate of does not answer the question.  I have already grouped the results by consecutive values successfully in my example below.  My question is how to populate a new column with the first value of each group.  Notice that state_start_value is not consecutive and so the linked answer does not apply.

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns.  One for the value and one for state.  I need to add another column which has the initial value at the start of the state, but I can't figure out how to do it.

from this:

```
df
    value   state
0   1   0
1   2   0
2   3   -1
3   4   -1
4   5   -1
5   6   0
6   7   1
7   8   0
8   9   0
```

I need:

```
    value   state   state_start_value
0   1   0   1
1   2   0   1
2   3   -1  3
3   4   -1  3
4   5   -1  3
5   6   0   6
6   7   1   7
7   8   0   8
8   9   0   8
```

I've tried adding column called state_count, so I can then group by that and get the initial state of each group. The resulting numbers are correct, they don't line up with the current rows.  And there must be a better way.

```
df['state_count'] = (df.state.diff() != 0).cumsum()
df['state_start_value'] = df.groupby('state_count')['value'].first()
```

yields

```
df
    value   state   state_count state_start_value
0   1   0   1   NaN
1   2   0   1   1.0
2   3   -1  2   3.0
3   4   -1  2   6.0
4   5   -1  2   7.0
5   6   0   3   8.0
6   7   1   4   NaN
7   8   0   5   NaN
8   9   0   5   NaN
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question.  In my example I have already grouped by consecutive values.  The question is how to populate a new column with the first value of each state group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['state_start_value'] = df.groupby((df.state != df.state.shift()).cumsum())['value'].transform('first')
```

Or to unpack it a bit:

```
change = df.state != df.state.shift()
cumulative_change = change.cumsum()
values_gb = df.groupby(cumulative_change)['value']
df['start_value'] = values_gb.transform('first')
```

The 'group by contiguous blocks' trick is borrowed from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40802853/4557382) answer by @jezrael.