# calculate max run length of groups of consecutive values in pandas

Tags: pandas

Given a dataset like this:

```
values = ([ 'motorway' ] * 5) + ([ 'link' ] * 3) + ([ 'motorway' ] * 7)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
  'timestamp': pd.date_range(start='2018-1-1', end='2018-1-2', freq='s').tolist()[:len(values)],
  'road_type': values,
})
df.set_index('timestamp')
df['delta_t'] = (df['timestamp'] - df['timestamp'].shift()).fillna(0)
```

I want to have the max sums of `delta_t` per group of consecutive road_types; given that `delta_t` is going to be `1s` in this sample case, I want to find `motorway`: `7s` and `link`: `3s`. In practice there will be more road_types, and `delta_t` will vary.

edit: the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802800/pandas-dataframe-how-to-groupby-consecutive-values) seems similar but does not sum the times nor does it select the largest of each groups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrame: How to groupby consecutive values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802800/pandas-dataframe-how-to-groupby-consecutive-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new column that labels each "run" of identical road types with a unique integer, then group by that column and sum:

```
df['run'] = (df['road_type'] != df['road_type'].shift()).astype(int).cumsum()

df
             timestamp road_type  delta_t  run
0  2018-01-01 00:00:00  motorway 00:00:00    1
1  2018-01-01 00:00:01  motorway 00:00:01    1
2  2018-01-01 00:00:02  motorway 00:00:01    1
3  2018-01-01 00:00:03  motorway 00:00:01    1
4  2018-01-01 00:00:04  motorway 00:00:01    1
5  2018-01-01 00:00:05      link 00:00:01    2
6  2018-01-01 00:00:06      link 00:00:01    2
7  2018-01-01 00:00:07      link 00:00:01    2
8  2018-01-01 00:00:08  motorway 00:00:01    3
9  2018-01-01 00:00:09  motorway 00:00:01    3
10 2018-01-01 00:00:10  motorway 00:00:01    3
11 2018-01-01 00:00:11  motorway 00:00:01    3
12 2018-01-01 00:00:12  motorway 00:00:01    3
13 2018-01-01 00:00:13  motorway 00:00:01    3
14 2018-01-01 00:00:14  motorway 00:00:01    3


df.groupby('run').agg({'road_type': 'first', 'delta_t': 'sum'}).reset_index(drop=True).groupby('road_type').max()

           delta_t
road_type         
link      00:00:03
motorway  00:00:07
```

Comment: Of these I only want the last two rows though.

Comment: wait -- df.groupby('run').agg({'road_type': 'first', 'delta_t': 'sum'}).reset_index(drop=True).groupby('road_type').max()
 does the job! Thanks!

Comment: @retorquere, sorry, I didn't read your question carefully enough! I'll edit your fix into the answer :)

Comment: No worries, this has helped me a lot. What does the "'road_type': 'first'" do?

Comment: That aggregates the `road_type` column by taking the first value of each group, but all the members of each group are the same, so '`first`' could be replaced with any aggfunc that works on non-numeric data types.