# Compute winning streak with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shift

I thought I knew how to do this but I'm pulling my hair out over it. I'm trying to use a function to create a new column. The function looks at the value of the win column in the current row and needs to compare it to the previous number in the win column as the if statements lay out below. The win column will only ever be 0 or 1.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'win': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]})
print (data)

   win
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    0
6    1

def streak(row):
    win_current_row = row['win']
    win_row_above = row['win'].shift(-1)
    streak_row_above = row['streak'].shift(-1)

    if (win_row_above == 0) & (win_current_row == 0):
        return 0
    elif (win_row_above == 0) & (win_current_row ==1):
        return 1
    elif (win_row_above ==1) & (win_current_row == 1):
        return streak_row_above + 1
    else:
        return 0

data['streak'] = data.apply(streak, axis=1)
```

All this ends with this error:

```
AttributeError: ("'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'shift'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

In other examples I see functions that are referring to `df['column'].shift(1)` so I'm confused why I can't seem to do it in this instance.

The output I'm trying to get too is:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'win': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], 'streak': ['NaN', 0 , 1, 2, 3, 0, 1]})
print(result)

   win streak
0    0    NaN
1    0      0 
2    1      1
3    1      2
4    1      3
5    0      0
6    1      1
```

Thanks for helping to get me unstuck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A fairly common trick when using `pandas` is grouping by consecutive values.  This trick is [well-described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802800/pandas-dataframe-how-to-groupby-consecutive-values).

To solve your particular problem, we want to `groupby` consecutive values, and then use `cumsum`, which means that groups of losses (groups of `0`) will have a cumulative sum of `0`, while groups of wins (or groups of `1`) will track winning streaks.

```
grouper = (df.win != df.win.shift()).cumsum()
df['streak'] = df.groupby(grouper).cumsum()
```

```
   win  streak
0    0       0
1    0       0
2    1       1
3    1       2
4    1       3
5    0       0
6    1       1
```

---

For the sake of explanation, here is our `grouper` `Series`, which allows us to group by continuous regions of `1`'s and `0`'s:

```
print(grouper)
```

```
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    4
Name: win, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks, I find this an easier to follow solution for my current skill level.

Answer (score 5):

Let's try `groupby` and `cumcount`:

```
m = df.win.astype(bool)
df['streak'] = (
    m.groupby([m, (~m).cumsum().where(m)]).cumcount().add(1).mul(m))

df
   win  streak
0    0       0
1    0       0
2    1       1
3    1       2
4    1       3
5    0       0
6    1       1
```

---

**How it Works**

Using `df.win.astype(bool)`, convert `df['win']` to its boolean equivalent (1=True, 0=False).

Next,

```
(~m).cumsum().where(m)

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
5    NaN
6    3.0
Name: win, dtype: float64
```

Represents all contiguous 1s with a unique number, with 0s being masked as NaN.

Now, use `groupby`, and `cumcount` to assign each row in the group with a monotonically increasing number.

```
m.groupby([m, (~m).cumsum().where(m)]).cumcount()

0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    2
6    0
dtype: int64
```

This is what we want but you can see it is 1) zero-based, and 2) also assigns values to the `0` (no win). We can use `m` to mask it (x times 1 (=True) is x, and anything times 0 (=False) is 0).

```
m.groupby([m, (~m).cumsum().where(m)]).cumcount().add(1).mul(m)

0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    0
6    1
dtype: int64
```

Assign this back in-place.

Comment: thank you. I can confirm this works on my larger dataset but it irks me I couldn't explain this back to anyone beyond the first step where you converted the series in booleans. Am I a few small tweaks away from a solution for a relative python newb above or am I way off here?

Comment: @mintgreenstrat Does it help that I edited my answer with explanation?

Comment: Yes, that helps and I can follow your explanation. Thank you. I have to be honest though, my Python brain isn't thinking on your level yet.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your getting that error is because shift() is pandas method. What your code was trying to do was getting the value at the in the row (row['win']) which is of numpy.int64. So you where trying to perform shift() on a numpy.int64. What this df['column'].shift(1) does is takes a dateframe column which is also a dataframe and shifts that column by 1.

To test this for yourself try
print(type(data['win']))
and
print(type(row['win']))
and
print(type(row))

That will tell you the datatype.

also your going to get an error when you get to
streak_row_above = row['streak'].shift(-1)

because your referring to row['streak'] before it is created.