# How to count the number of days since a column flag?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe defined as follows. I'd like to count the number of days (or rows) when the `input` column changes from 1 to 0:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'input': [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]}, 
                  index=pd.date_range('2021-10-01', periods=12))
# I can mark the points of interest, i.e. when it goes from 1 to 0
df['change'] = 0
df.loc[(df['input'].shift(1) - df['input']) > 0, 'change'] = 1
print(df)
```

I end up with the following:

```
            input   change
2021-10-01      1        0
2021-10-02      1        0 
2021-10-03      1        0
2021-10-04      0        1
2021-10-05      0        0
2021-10-06      0        0
2021-10-07      1        0
2021-10-08      1        0
2021-10-09      1        0
2021-10-10      0        1
2021-10-11      0        0
2021-10-12      0        0
```

What I want is a `res` output:

```
            input   change     res
2021-10-01      1        0       0
2021-10-02      1        0       0  
2021-10-03      1        0       0
2021-10-04      0        1       1
2021-10-05      0        0       2
2021-10-06      0        0       3
2021-10-07      1        0       0
2021-10-08      1        0       0
2021-10-09      1        0       0
2021-10-10      0        1       1
2021-10-11      0        0       2
2021-10-12      0        0       3
```

I know I can use a `cumsum` but don't find a way to "reset it" at the appropriate points:

```
df['res'] = (1 - df['input']).cumsum()*(1 - df['input'])
```

but this above will continue accumulating and not reset where `change == 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a boolean Series only where `input` [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) `0` then [group by consecutive values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40802800/15497888) and take the [`groupby cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) of the boolean Series. This is essentially enumerating groups, but only groups where there are 0s in `input`.

`0`:

```
m = df['input'].eq(0)
df['res'] = m.groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()).cumsum()
```

`df`:

```
            input  change  res
2021-10-01      1       0    0
2021-10-02      1       0    0
2021-10-03      1       0    0
2021-10-04      0       1    1
2021-10-05      0       0    2
2021-10-06      0       0    3
2021-10-07      1       0    0
2021-10-08      1       0    0
2021-10-09      1       0    0
2021-10-10      0       1    1
2021-10-11      0       0    2
2021-10-12      0       0    3
```

Comment: Wow super clever algorithm :) awesome! thanks a lot!

Comment: NP. Just a couple tricks put together, although they work together nicely here. :-)