# Find duplicates in dataframe and keep only the highest ones

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-manipulation

I'm trying to find the duplicates in a dataframe for each group that are higher so I can remove these later from another dataframe based on the index so the main dataframe is left with no duplicates and only the lowest value.

Basically let's say we have this dataframe:

```py
index   group   value
  1       1      402
  2       1      396
  3       2      406
  4       2      416
  5       2      407
  6       2      406
  7       1      200
  8       2      350
```

What I need is to only keep the duplicates in each group of consecutive duplicates that have the highest values and remove the lowest one. The group is 1 or 2 but there can be multiple instances of consecutive values in the same group.
So the resulting dataframe would be:

```py
index   group   value
  1       1      402
  4       2      416
  5       2      407
```

Speed is important too and there has to be no lookahead.

Comment: Does it need to maintain original order/index?

Comment: From the result you gave, it appears you only want to drop the lowest value in each group (if there are multiple values)?

Comment: yes, it needs to maintain the index, in fact the index is the only thing that I'm interested in. And that's correct, I want to drop the lowest value in each group.

Comment: why should 416 and 407 remain if they are both in the same group 2?

Comment: because they are higher than 406 which is the lowest value in the group

Comment: Given OP's (albeit limited and confusing?) description, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802800/how-to-groupby-consecutive-values-in-pandas-dataframe) seems relevant

Comment: If @HarryPlotter and I are understanding the intent correctly, please edit the title of this question to more accurately reflect intent.

Comment: I've updated the description, I hope it makes more sense

Comment: It's clear now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be made easier with [rank()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html).
In this case, you need to decide how to deal with the same minimum values - delete one of them (`method = 'first'`) or both (`method = 'min'`). Based on the condition "remove the *lowest one*" in the solution set `method = 'first'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'group': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
                   'value': [402, 396, 406, 416, 407, 200, 350]}).set_index('index')
print('Source df:\n', df)
df = df[df.groupby(df.group.diff().ne(0).cumsum())['value'].rank(method='first').gt(1)]
print('\nResult df:\n', df)
```

Output:

```
Source df:
        group  value
index              
1          1    402
2          1    396
3          2    406
4          2    416
5          2    407
6          1    200
7          2    350

Result df:
        group  value
index              
1          1    402
4          2    416
5          2    407
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working, it still has all the values in the group

Comment: This is weird. It works for me, see full example and result above. Just in case, replaced `.ne(1)` with `.gt(1)`

Comment: still doesn't work with my data, not sure why. I've accepted @HarryPlotter's solution which works, thanks any way

Comment: The reason for the difference from the expected result was that I did not read the clarification about sequential groups after updating the description. The code has been updated.

Comment: Yep it's working now thanks!

Comment: do you know what would I need to change if I wanted to delete the maximum instead of the minimum? Is it ascending=False on rank? seems to be working

Comment: yes, this change is enough

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` + `transform` to mask the minimum values of each group. Then use the mask to select only the desired rows.

```
# map each consecutive group of rows to a different integer
group_labels = (df.group != df.group.shift()).cumsum()

# find the minimum value of each group 
group_min_val = df.groupby(group_labels)['value'].transform('min')

# get only the rows of each group whose value is higher than the minimum 
res = df[df.value != group_min_val]

>>> res

   index  group  value
0      1      1    402
3      4      2    416
4      5      2    407
```

**Intermediate Results**

```
>>> group_labels

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    4
Name: group, dtype: int64

>>> group_min_val

0    396
1    396
2    406
3    406
4    406
5    406
6    200
7    350
Name: value, dtype: int64

>>> df.value != group_min_val

0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: value, dtype: bool
```

Comment: the problem is that you could have multiple groups so this would group them all, what I need is the minimum in each group set. I've updated the dataframe

Comment: @AlexBejan what do you mean by 'group'?

Comment: @AlexBejan I have updated the answer. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @HarryPlotter instead of using `!=` consider `df1.ne(df2)`

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp I'm aware of that, but honestly, I prefer this way, I think it's more readable!  But it's just a matter of preference

Comment: excellent, working like a charm, thank you sir!

Comment: @AlexBejan you're welcome, I'm glad I could help!

Comment: @HarryPlotter actually is there a way to make this work if there are 2 equal minimum values? Looks like right now it keeps both so I end up with duplicates again :)

Comment: @AlexBejan Can you share an example of the data and your code in a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) (or something similar)? The code should remove all the minimum values of all groups, whether there is just a single or multiple minimums per group.

Comment: @HarryPlotter I've updated the example, see index 6 which is the same as 3

Comment: @AlexBejan I don't understand what you mean. The solution works with the new example, I get the expected output. I've updated my answer with the new example, you can check it.  Maybe you're doing something else that you aren't telling me.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner version of @HarryPlotter's answer:

```py
df.loc[df.value.ne(df.groupby(df.group.ne(df.group.shift()).cumsum()).value.transform('min'))]
```

using the trick from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802800/how-to-groupby-consecutive-values-in-pandas-dataframe) to apply OP's understanding of "grouping", and transforming to get the minimum value in each group, and then `.loc`-ing for all values *not equal* to those.

**WARNING**: this *drops* any singleton "groups"! (Where OP's comments indicate "keep all but the lowest," this discards singleton values that would technically also be the 'highest' in their group.)