# What is the best approach to this issue related to cumulative sum per section?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sum

I have this information:
[0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1]

and need add successively 15 only in the section between zeros, as result:
[0,15,30,45,60,75,0,15,30,45,0,15,30,45,60,0,15,30,45]

Comment: You can use the trick from here to select your groups: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802800/how-to-groupby-consecutive-values-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: `s=pd.Series(arr); s.groupby(s.eq(0).cumsum()).cumcount() * 15`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy
l = np.array([0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1])
l *= 15
s = np.hstack([np.cumsum(v) for v in np.split(l, np.where(l==0)[0])])
print(s)
```

`np.split` takes an array to be split, and an iterable of cuts. `np.where` gives you all of the indices `i` where `l[i] == 0`. `np.cumsum` does the cumulative sum on all of these, and then `np.hstack` puts them all back together.

Comment: I wonder why the -1's. I wasn't trying to golf this, this is how I would do it.

Answer (score -1):

Pseudo code

```
create an empty list which will be the result
initialize a counter at 0
for each element of the original list
    add 1 to the counter if the element is not 0 else reset the counter to 0
    append to the result list 15 times the counter
```