# Python count by group ordered by date, restarting if gap between groups

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add up how many times a drug is rejected before it is approved. Patients can go through this process each time they fill their prescription, therefore I don't want to just count by group because then that will tell me how many times a drug is rejected within the time frame.

I think it might be a combination of a window function and cumcount but it isn't working.

This is what I've done:

```
subset['cumcount'] = subset.sort_values(['patient_id','date']).groupby(['patient_key','claim_type','drug'])['count'].cumcount(1)
```

Which results in the following table:

| patient_id | date | claim_type | drug | cumcount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pat_1 | 2022-07-20 | rejection | drug_a | 0 |
| pat_1 | 2022-07-22 | rejection | drug_a | 1 |
| pat_1 | 2022-07-22 | approval | drug_a | 0 |
| pat_1 | 2022-08-17 | rejection | drug_a | 2 |
| pat_1 | 2022-08-18 | rejection | drug_a | 3 |
| pat_1 | 2022-08-18 | approval | drug_a | 1 |

But this is the table I want:

| patient_id | date | claim_type | drug | cumcount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pat_1 | 2022-07-20 | rejection | drug_a | 2 |
| pat_1 | 2022-07-22 | approval | drug_a | 1 |
| pat_1 | 2022-08-17 | rejection | drug_a | 2 |
| pat_1 | 2022-08-18 | approval | drug_a | 1 |

My plan is to then separate all the rejections out and join with approvals if within <7 days after first rejection.

Comment: See if the following gives you some ideas:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73758489/gaps-and-islands-python-dataframe-pandas

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802800/how-to-groupby-consecutive-values-in-pandas-dataframe