# Identify consecutive same values in Pandas Dataframe, with a Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda

I have the following dataframe df:

```
data={'id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
      'value':[2,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,4,1,1,1,4,4,1,1,1,1,1]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
Out[8]: 
    id  value
0    1      2
1    1      2
2    1      3
3    1      2
4    1      2
5    1      2
6    1      3
7    1      3
8    1      3
9    1      3
10   2      1
11   2      4
12   2      1
13   2      1
14   2      1
15   2      4
16   2      4
17   2      1
18   2      1
19   2      1
20   2      1
21   2      1
```

What I need to do is identify at the id level (df.groupby['id']) when the value shows the same number consecutively for 3 or more times.

I would like to have the following result for the above:

```
df
Out[12]: 
    id  value  flag
0    1      2     0
1    1      2     0
2    1      3     0
3    1      2     1
4    1      2     1
5    1      2     1
6    1      3     1
7    1      3     1
8    1      3     1
9    1      3     1
10   2      1     0
11   2      4     0
12   2      1     1
13   2      1     1
14   2      1     1
15   2      4     0
16   2      4     0
17   2      1     1
18   2      1     1
19   2      1     1
20   2      1     1
21   2      1     1
```

I have tried variations of groupby and lambda using pandas rolling.mean to identify where the average of the rolling period is then compared to the 'value', and where they are the same this indicates a flag.  But this has several problems, including that you could have different values that will average to the value you are trying to flag.  Also, I can't figure out how to 'flag' all of the values of the rolling mean that created the initial flag.  See here, this identifies the 'right side' of the flag, but then I need to fill the previous values of the rolling mean length.  See my code here:

```
test=df.copy()
test['rma']=test.groupby('id')['value'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(min_periods=3,window=3).mean())
test['flag']=np.where(test.rma==test.value,1,0)
```

And the result here:

```
test
Out[61]: 
    id  value       rma  flag
0    1      2       NaN     0
1    1      2       NaN     0
2    1      3  2.333333     0
3    1      2  2.333333     0
4    1      2  2.333333     0
5    1      2  2.000000     1
6    1      3  2.333333     0
7    1      3  2.666667     0
8    1      3  3.000000     1
9    1      3  3.000000     1
10   2      1       NaN     0
11   2      4       NaN     0
12   2      1  2.000000     0
13   2      1  2.000000     0
14   2      1  1.000000     1
15   2      4  2.000000     0
16   2      4  3.000000     0
17   2      1  3.000000     0
18   2      1  2.000000     0
19   2      1  1.000000     1
20   2      1  1.000000     1
21   2      1  1.000000     1
```

Can't wait to see what I am missing!  Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about your output?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can try this; 1) Create an extra group variable with `df.value.diff().ne(0).cumsum()` to denote the value changes; 2) use `transform('size')` to calculate the group size and compare with three, then you get the `flag` column you need:

```
df['flag'] = df.value.groupby([df.id, df.value.diff().ne(0).cumsum()]).transform('size').ge(3).astype(int) 
df
```

[image]

---

*Break downs*:

1) *`diff` is not equal to zero* (which is literally what `df.value.diff().ne(0)` means) gives a condition `True` whenever there is a value change:

```
df.value.diff().ne(0)
#0      True
#1     False
#2      True
#3      True
#4     False
#5     False
#6      True
#7     False
#8     False
#9     False
#10     True
#11     True
#12     True
#13    False
#14    False
#15     True
#16    False
#17     True
#18    False
#19    False
#20    False
#21    False
#Name: value, dtype: bool
```

2) Then `cumsum` gives a non descending sequence of ids where each id denotes a consecutive chunk with same values, note when summing boolean values, `True` is considered as one while `False` is considered as zero:

```
df.value.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
#0     1
#1     1
#2     2
#3     3
#4     3
#5     3
#6     4
#7     4
#8     4
#9     4
#10    5
#11    6
#12    7
#13    7
#14    7
#15    8
#16    8
#17    9
#18    9
#19    9
#20    9
#21    9
#Name: value, dtype: int64
```

3) combined with `id` column, you can group the data frame, calculate the group size and get the `flag` column.

Answer (score 7):

**See EDIT2 for a more robust solution**

Same result, but a little bit faster:

```python
labels = (df.value != df.value.shift()).cumsum()
df['flag'] = (labels.map(labels.value_counts()) >= 3).astype(int)

    id  value  flag
0    1      2     0
1    1      2     0
2    1      3     0
3    1      2     1
4    1      2     1
5    1      2     1
6    1      3     1
7    1      3     1
8    1      3     1
9    1      3     1
10   2      1     0
11   2      4     0
12   2      1     1
13   2      1     1
14   2      1     1
15   2      4     0
16   2      4     0
17   2      1     1
18   2      1     1
19   2      1     1
20   2      1     1
21   2      1     1
```

Where:

1. `df.value != df.value.shift()` gives the value change
2. `cumsum()` creates "labels" for each group of same value
3. `labels.value_counts()` counts the occurrences of each label
4. `labels.map(...)` replaces labels by the counts computed above
5. `>= 3` creates a boolean mask on count value
6. `astype(int)` casts the booleans to int

In my hands it give 1.03ms on your df, compared to 2.1ms for Psidoms' approach.
But mine is not one-liner.

---

EDIT:

A mix between both approaches is even faster

```python
labels = df.value.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
df['flag'] = (labels.map(labels.value_counts()) >= 3).astype(int)
```

Gives 911µs with your sample df.

---

EDIT2: correct solution to account for id change, as pointed by @clg4

```python
labels = (df.value.diff().ne(0) | df.id.diff().ne(0)).cumsum()
df['flag'] = (labels.map(labels.value_counts()) >= 3).astype(int)
```

Where `... | df.id.diff().ne(0)` increment the label where the id changes

This works even with same value on id change (tested with value 3 on index 10) and takes 1.28ms

EDIT3: Better explanations

Take the case where index 10 has value 3. `df.id.diff().ne(0)`

```python
data={'id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
      'value':[2,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,1,1,1,4,4,1,1,1,1,1]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df['id_diff'] = df.id.diff().ne(0).astype(int)
df['val_diff'] = df.value.diff().ne(0).astype(int)
df['diff_or'] = (df.id.diff().ne(0) | df.value.diff().ne(0)).astype(int)
df['labels'] = df['diff_or'].cumsum()

     id  value  id_diff  val_diff  diff_or  labels
 0    1      2        1         1        1       1
 1    1      2        0         0        0       1
 2    1      3        0         1        1       2
 3    1      2        0         1        1       3
 4    1      2        0         0        0       3
 5    1      2        0         0        0       3
 6    1      3        0         1        1       4
 7    1      3        0         0        0       4
 8    1      3        0         0        0       4
 9    1      3        0         0        0       4
>10   2      3        1    |    0    =   1       5 <== label increment
 11   2      4        0         1        1       6
 12   2      1        0         1        1       7
 13   2      1        0         0        0       7
 14   2      1        0         0        0       7
 15   2      4        0         1        1       8
 16   2      4        0         0        0       8
 17   2      1        0         1        1       9
 18   2      1        0         0        0       9
 19   2      1        0         0        0       9
 20   2      1        0         0        0       9
 21   2      1        0         0        0       9
```

The `|` is operator "bitwise-or", which gives `True` as long as one of the elements is `True`. So if there is no diff in value where the id changes, the `|` reflects the id change. Otherwise it changes nothing.
When `.cumsum()` is performed, the label is incremented where the id changes, so the value `3` at index 10 is not grouped with values `3` from indexes 6-9.

Comment: this is helpful.   Your process requires that the id be sorted.  I know I did not require that based on my input, but the groupby deals with that as well.  To bullet proof your solution you would need a sort id first.  correct?

Comment: @clg4: well, sorting the id will change the sequence of the values, so if the ids are mixed it will also change the output of the algorithm. This is up to you. Plus I am not sure that df.sort by column will preserve intra-group row ordering. Groupby is probably better if you want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
#try this simpler version
a= pd.Series([1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,7,8,0,0,0])
b= a.groupby([a.ne(0), a]).transform('size').ge(3).astype('int')
#ge(x) <- x is the number of consecutive repeated values 
print b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
      return dd.assign(flag=0) if len(dd)<3 else dd.assign(flag=1)

col1=df['value'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
df.assign(flag=col1).groupby(['id','flag']).apply(function1)
```

out：

```
    id  value  flag
0    1      2     0
1    1      2     0
2    1      3     0
3    1      2     1
4    1      2     1
5    1      2     1
6    1      3     1
7    1      3     1
8    1      3     1
9    1      3     1
10   2      1     0
11   2      4     0
12   2      1     1
13   2      1     1
14   2      1     1
15   2      4     0
16   2      4     0
17   2      1     1
18   2      1     1
19   2      1     1
20   2      1     1
21   2      1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        {'id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
         'value':[2,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,4,1,1,1,4,4,1,1,1,1,1]})

df2 = df.groupby((df['value'].shift() != df['value']).\
                cumsum()).filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3)

df['flag'] = np.where(df.index.isin(df2.index),1,0)
```