# How to calculate continuous increase count number for pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the future continuous increase or decrease count for each element.

Assume I have a series:

```
l=[10, 9, 8, 9, 10, 9, 10, 11, 10, 12, 10]
s=pd.Series(l)
```

The expected output is:

```
o=[-2, -1, 2, 1, -1, 2, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0]
```

Here is the explanation:

the first element is 10, the next is 9, the next is 8, so, it decrease 2 times, so the output is -2, for the third element is 8, it increase 2 times (the next is 9, 10), so output is 2.

The key point is continuous, once it has reverse data, it should be stop look forward.

How can I implement that? I think for loop is not good enough

Comment: Something for you to start with `np.sign(-s.diff(-1).fillna(0))`

Comment: @xyhuang : Does the answer helps? or you are still stuck?

Comment: @Pygirl thanks, i think your answer is good, but i want to know if there is some matrix method we can use, for loop maybe not the fastest

Comment: I have updated my answer also gave you pandas solution. This will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119524/pandas-conditional-rolling-count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st get the sign of difference. Then find how many are consecutive same sign. If same then add the quantity.
try:

```
import numpy as np
l=np.array([10, 9, 8, 9, 10, 9, 10, 11, 10, 12, 10])
sign = np.sign(np.diff(l))
count = {}
for i in range(len(sign)-1):
    count[i] = sign[i]
    for j in range(i+1, len(sign)):
        if sign[i]==sign[j]:
            count[i] += sign[j]
        else:
            break
count[i+1] = 0
res = count.values()
```

---

**res:**

```
dict_values([-2, -1, 2, 1, -1, 2, 1, -1, 1, 0])
```

**Edit:**

If you want to use `pandas`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sign, columns=['col'])
df = df[::-1]
x = df.groupby((df['col'] != df['col'].shift(1)).cumsum()).cumsum()['col']
x.iloc[0]=0
x = x.values[::-1]
```

---

**x:**

```
array([-2, -1,  2,  1, -1,  2,  1, -1,  1,  0])
```

---

instead of :

```
(df['col'] != df['col'].shift(1)).cumsum()
```

you can use

```
df.col.diff().ne(0).cumsum()
```

[Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45886579/6660373)