# How to get the cumulative count based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say we have the following dataframe. If we wanted to find the count of consecutive 1's, you could use the below.

```
    col
0   0
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   0
5   0
6   1
7   1
8   0
9   1
10  1
11  1
12  1
13  0
14  1
15  1


df['col'].groupby(df['col'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumsum()
```

But the problem I see is when you need to use `groupby` with and id field. If we added an `id` field to the dataframe (below), it makes it more complicated. We can no longer use the solution above.

```
    id  col
0   B   0
1   B   1
2   B   1
3   B   1
4   A   0
5   A   0
6   B   1
7   B   1
8   B   0
9   B   1
10  B   1
11  A   1
12  A   1
13  A   0
14  A   1
15  A   1
```

When presented with this issue, ive seen the case for making a helper series to use in the groupby like this:

```
s = df['col'].eq(0).groupby(df['id']).cumsum()
df['col'].groupby([df['id'],s]).cumsum()
```

Which works, but the problem is that the first group contains the first row, which does not fit the criteria. This usually isn't a problem, but it is if we wanted to find the count. Replacing `cumsum()` at the end of the last `groupby()` with `.transform('count')` would actually give us `6` instead of `5` for the count of consecutive 1's in the first B group.

The only solution I can come up with for this problem is the following code:

```
df['col'].groupby([df['id'],df.groupby('id')['col'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().ne(0).astype(int).cumsum())]).transform('count')
```

Expected output:

```
0     1
1     5
2     5
3     5
4     2
5     2
6     5
7     5
8     1
9     2
10    2
11    2
12    2
13    1
14    2
15    2
```

This works, but uses `transform()` twice, which I heard isn't the fastest. It is the only solution I can think of that uses `diff().ne(0)` to get the "real" groups.

Index 1,2,3,6 and 7 are all id B, with the same value in the `'col'` column, so the count would not be reset, so they would all be apart of the same group.

Can this be done without using multiple `.transform()`?

Comment: I think i was going for a twist on the accepted answer on this question. I think that solution would only work if the `id's` are sorted first. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886518/identify-consecutive-same-values-in-pandas-dataframe-with-a-groupby/45886579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The following code uses only 1 `.transform()`, and relies upon ordering the index, to get the correct counts.

  - The original index is kept, so the final result can be reindexed back to the original order.
- Use `cum_counts['cum_counts']` to get the exact desired output, without the other column.

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data as shown in OP
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 'col': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]})

# reset the index, then set the index and sort
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['index', 'id']).sort_index(level=1) 

          col
index id     
4     A     0
5     A     0
11    A     1
12    A     1
13    A     0
14    A     1
15    A     1
0     B     0
1     B     1
2     B     1
3     B     1
6     B     1
7     B     1
8     B     0
9     B     1
10    B     1
```

```py
# get the cumulative sum
g = df.col.ne(df.col.shift()).cumsum()

# use g to groupby and use only 1 transform to get the counts
cum_counts = df['col'].groupby(g).transform('count').reset_index(level=1, name='cum_counts').sort_index()

      id  cum_counts
index               
0      B           1
1      B           5
2      B           5
3      B           5
4      A           2
5      A           2
6      B           5
7      B           5
8      B           1
9      B           2
10     B           2
11     A           2
12     A           2
13     A           1
14     A           2
15     A           2
```

Comment: Ah... this makes sense for his deisred solution.  Great answer.

Comment: @rhug123 you're welcome, I'm glad this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at @TrentonMcKinney solution, I came up with:

```
df = df.sort_values(['id'])
grp =(df[['id','col']] != df[['id','col']].shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
df['count'] = df.groupby(grp)['id'].transform('count')
df.sort_index()
```

Output:

```
   id  col  count
0   B    0      1
1   B    1      5
2   B    1      5
3   B    1      5
4   A    0      2
5   A    0      2
6   B    1      5
7   B    1      5
8   B    0      1
9   B    1      2
10  B    1      2
11  A    1      2
12  A    1      2
13  A    0      1
14  A    1      2
15  A    1      2
```

---

IIUC, do you want?

```
grp = (df[['id', 'col']] != df[['id', 'col']].shift()).any(axis = 1).cumsum()
df['count'] = df.groupby(grp)['id'].transform('count')
df
```

Output:

```
   id  col  count
0   B    0      1
1   B    1      3
2   B    1      3
3   B    1      3
4   A    0      2
5   A    0      2
6   B    1      2
7   B    1      2
8   B    0      1
9   B    1      2
10  B    1      2
11  A    1      2
12  A    1      2
13  A    0      1
14  A    1      2
15  A    1      2
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great way to solve this problem!