# Sequentially number groups with common groupby values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have some classes that are continuous data and integers. I would like to sequentially number each common block of class integers sequentially as the index increases.

Here's my code including dummy data and what I've tried with ngroup

```
import pandas as pd

# Dummy data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Index': range(36),
    'KAGG': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'Desired result': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
})


data["SEQ"] = data.groupby("KAGG").ngroup()+1

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,8))

ax1.plot(data['KAGG'], data['Index'])
ax2.plot(data['SEQ'], data['Index'])
ax3.plot(data['Desired result'], data['Index'])
```

The current result and the desired result are pictured below, plots are from left to right: dummy data, my attempt, and the desired resut.
[image: Desired result]

So the following answer worked:

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886518/identify-consecutive-same-values-in-pandas-dataframe-with-a-groupby)

code:

```
# Create the dummy data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Index': range(36),
    'KAGG': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'Desired result': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
})

# Calculate the label increments
data['diff_or'] = data['KAGG'].diff().ne(0).astype(int)
data['labels'] = data['diff_or'].cumsum()

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True, sharey=True, figsize=(10,8))

ax1.plot(data['KAGG'], data['Index'])
ax2.plot(data['labels'], data['Index']);
```

Comment: `df['KAGG'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()`