# Count consecutives values in time series

Tags: python, pandas, count, trend

It's my first time asking a question here, so I hope I will do it right !

I have a Pandas Dataframe:

```
df2.data
Out[66]: 
date
2016-01-02    0.0
2016-01-03    1.0
2016-01-04    1.0
2016-01-05    1.0
2016-01-06    0.0
2016-01-07    0.0
2016-01-08    1.0
2016-01-09    2.0
2016-01-10    1.0
2016-01-11    0.0
Name: data, dtype: float64
```

I would like the following results :

```
            data  trend  trend_type
date                               
2016-01-02   0.0      0           0
2016-01-03   1.0      0           0
2016-01-04   1.0      1           1
2016-01-05   1.0      2           1
2016-01-06   0.0      0           0
2016-01-07   0.0      1           0
2016-01-08   1.0      0           0
2016-01-09   2.0      0           0
2016-01-10   1.0      0           0
2016-01-11   0.0      0           0
```

My probleme is a bit related with [How to use pandas to find consecutive same data in time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911851/how-to-use-pandas-to-find-consecutive-same-data-in-time-series).

So far, I managed to get the trend, but it is not efficient enough (about 8 sec for a 750 rows dataframe)

```
df['grp'] = (df.close.diff(1) == 0).astype('int')
df['trend'] = 0
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(2, len(df['grp'])):
    if df.grp.iloc[i] == 1:
        df['trend'].iloc[i] = df['trend'].iloc[i-1] + 1
```

Comment: What is `trend_type`? Can you explain how you get these results?

Comment: To get the trend, you can very easily do a groupby - `df.date.groupby(df.date.ne(df.date.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()`

Comment: If you can explain what `trend_type` is, that would be great.

Comment: Hello. Sorry it wasnt clear enough. Trend type is whether the trend (serie of conscutive data) is a 0, 1 or 2. By default it is a 0. I wrote those results.

Comment: It's still not obvious how you calculate it. Your data and your explanation do not add up..

Comment: Going by your explanation, I should have `0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0`.

Comment: For a given date, I would like to know if there are consecutive identical data, if there is, I would like to know for how many days and what was the data.

Comment: Okay, in your data, all dates are distinct, so shouldn't everything be 0 in `trend_type`?

Comment: I understand, so since on days 2016-01-06 and 2016-01-07 the data is '0', the trend type is 0. If the data were 1, the trend type would be 1, and if the data were 2, the trend type 2

Comment: Alright, see if my answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**
To get `trend`, perform a `groupby` + `cumcount` -

```
df['trend'] = df.data.groupby(df.data.ne(df.data.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()
df

            data  trend
2016-01-02   0.0      0
2016-01-03   1.0      0
2016-01-04   1.0      1
2016-01-05   1.0      2
2016-01-06   0.0      0
2016-01-07   0.0      1
2016-01-08   1.0      0
2016-01-09   2.0      0
2016-01-10   1.0      0
2016-01-11   0.0      0
```

**Step 2**
(IIUC), to get `trend_type`, compare consecutive rows and assign.

```
df['trend_type'] = 0
m = df.data.eq(df.data.shift())
df.loc[m, 'trend_type'] = df.loc[m, 'data']

df

            data  trend  trend_type
2016-01-02   0.0      0         0.0
2016-01-03   1.0      0         0.0
2016-01-04   1.0      1         1.0
2016-01-05   1.0      2         1.0
2016-01-06   0.0      0         0.0
2016-01-07   0.0      1         0.0
2016-01-08   1.0      0         0.0
2016-01-09   2.0      0         0.0
2016-01-10   1.0      0         0.0
2016-01-11   0.0      0         0.0
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you very much for your help ! And the execution is really fast, that's perfect ! I wish you a very nice day, you just made mine !

Answer (score 0):

Edit, add column "trep_type"

```
df.loc[0, "trend"] = 0
df.loc[0, "trend_type"] = 0

for nrow in range(df.shape[0]-1):

    if df.loc[nrow+1, 1] == df.loc[nrow, 1]:
        df.loc[nrow+1, "trend"] = df.loc[nrow, "trend"]+1
        df.loc[nrow + 1, "trend_type"] = 1
    else:
        df.loc[nrow + 1, "trend"] = 0
        df.loc[nrow + 1, "trend_type"] = 0
```

Comment: thanks for the intereset on my question Manuel ! I think your solution is a bit like my first attempt, the problem is the time of execution