# Find begin and end index of consecutive ones in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
     A    B    C
0    1    1    1
1    0    1    0
2    1    1    1
3    1    0    1
4    1    1    0
5    1    1    0 
6    0    1    1
7    0    1    0
```

of which I want to know the start and end index when the values are 1 for 3 or more consecutive values per column. Desired outcome:

```
Column    From    To    
     A       2     5
     B       1     3         
     B       4     7
```

first I filter out the ones that are not consecutive for 3 or more values

```
filtered_df = df.copy().apply(filter, threshold=3)
```

where

```
def filter(col, threshold=3):  
    mask = col.groupby((col != col.shift()).cumsum()).transform('count').lt(threshold)
    mask &= col.eq(1)
    col.update(col.loc[mask].replace(1,0))
    return col
```

`filtered_df` now look as:

```
     A    B    C
0    0    1    0
1    0    1    0
2    1    1    0
3    1    0    0
4    1    1    0
5    1    1    0 
6    0    1    0
7    0    1    0
```

If the dataframe would have only one column with zeros and ones the result could be achieved as in [How to use pandas to find consecutive same data in time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911851/how-to-use-pandas-to-find-consecutive-same-data-in-time-series). However, I am struggeling to do something similar for multiple columns at once.

Comment: Perhaps package your code in a function and then apply the function to the dataframe as a whole? You'd of course need to extend the `filter` function to apply it for each col in df.columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) for apply function for all `DataFrame`.

In first solution get first and last value of consecutive `1` per each columns, add output to lists and last `concat`:

```
def f(df, threshold=3): 
    out = []
    for col in df.columns:
        m = df[col].eq(1)
        g = (df[col] != df[col].shift()).cumsum()[m]
        mask = g.groupby(g).transform('count').ge(threshold)
        filt = g[mask].reset_index()
        output = filt.groupby(col)['index'].agg(['first','last'])
        output.insert(0, 'col', col)
        out.append(output)

    return pd.concat(out, ignore_index=True)
```

Or first reshape by `unstack` and then apply solution:

```
def f(df, threshold=3):

    df1 = df.unstack().rename_axis(('col','idx')).reset_index(name='val')
    m = df1['val'].eq(1)
    g = (df1['val'] != df1.groupby('col')['val'].shift()).cumsum()
    mask = g.groupby(g).transform('count').ge(threshold) & m
    return (df1[mask].groupby([df1['col'], g])['idx']
                    .agg(['first','last'])
                    .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                    .reset_index())


filtered_df = df.pipe(f, threshold=3)
print (filtered_df)
  col  first  last
0   A      2     5
1   B      0     2
2   B      4     7
```

```
filtered_df = df.pipe(f, threshold=2)
print (filtered_df)
  col  first  last
0   A      2     5
1   B      0     2
2   B      4     7
3   C      2     3
```

Comment: Thanks! Both methods work. Is one of them better than the other?

Comment: @Peter - Hard question, second should be slowier if many groups, many columns. The best test in real data both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) to create a window over the data frame. Then you can apply all your conditions and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) the window back to its start location:

```
length = 3
window = df.rolling(length)
mask = (window.min() == 1) & (window.max() == 1)
mask = mask.shift(1 - length)
print(mask)
```

which prints:

```
       A      B      C
0  False   True  False
1  False  False  False
2   True  False  False
3   True  False  False
4  False   True  False
5  False   True  False
6    NaN    NaN    NaN
7    NaN    NaN    NaN
```