# How to identify consecutive same values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data fame like that :

| Timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-04-21 14:22:00 | 0 |
| 2021-04-21 14:23:00 | 0 |
| 2021-04-21 14:24:00 | 0 |
| 2021-04-21 14:25:00 | 1 |
| 2021-04-21 14:26:00 | 1 |
| 2021-04-21 14:27:00 | 0 |
| 2021-04-21 14:28:00 | 1 |
| 2021-04-21 14:29:00 | 1 |
| 2021-04-21 14:30:00 | 1 |

I wan to get the consecutive same values like that :

| Begin Date | Another header | Consecutive values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-21 14:25:00 | 2021-04-21 14:26:00 | 2 |
| 2021-04-21 14:28:00 | 2021-04-21 14:30:00 | 3 |

I tried some solutions with numpy shift, or by using for / while loop, but it don't work ... Also, I saw some topics in stack overflow indeed.

Thanks !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use pandas to find consecutive same data in time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911851/how-to-use-pandas-to-find-consecutive-same-data-in-time-series)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first group the values by using `df.diff(1)` and `.cumsum()`:

```
df['group'] = (df.Value.diff(1) != 0).cumsum()
```

Now we can use `pd.groupby()` on this column to create your new dataframe:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'Begin Date' : df.groupby('group').Timestamp.first(), 
                    'Another header' : df.groupby('group').Timestamp.last(),
                    'Consecutive values' : df.groupby('group').size(),
                    'Value' : df.groupby('group').Value.first()}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
             Begin Date        Another header  Consecutive values  Value
0  2021-04-21 14:22:00   2021-04-21 14:24:00                    3      0
1  2021-04-21 14:25:00   2021-04-21 14:26:00                    2      1
2  2021-04-21 14:27:00   2021-04-21 14:27:00                    1      0
3  2021-04-21 14:28:00   2021-04-21 14:30:00                    3      1
```

I deliberately show here the complete result (including consecutive zeroes). If you wish to delete those you can filter by doing `out[out.Value != 0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
# identify rows with value=1
m = df['Value'].eq(1)

# filter, groupby consecutive values
out = (df[m].groupby((~m).cumsum())
             # aggregate with first/min, last/max date, and count
            .agg(**{'Begin Date': ('Timestamp', 'first'),    # or min
                    'Another header': ('Timestamp', 'last'), # or max
                    'Consecutive values': ('Timestamp', 'count')})
      )
```

output:

```
                Begin Date       Another header  Consecutive values
Value                                                              
3      2021-04-21 14:25:00  2021-04-21 14:26:00                   2
4      2021-04-21 14:28:00  2021-04-21 14:30:00                   3
```

Comment: I think it is better to drop the index here (or add them as a column and make sure they have the right value)

Comment: @TCMolenaar you can prevent using the grouper as index in groupby or `reset_index(drop=True)` if needed ;)

Comment: I know, but don't you think it's better to add that? It's a bit confusing now as there is no value 3 or 4